# How to create a histogram

Tags: c#, image, histogram, emgucv

I want to create a histogram within a C# program that uses EMGU.  EMGU contains a class called MCvHistogram in it, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: This article shows how to create histogram in RGB 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204822/how-to-draw-histogram-using-emgucv-and-c-sharp

Answer (score 11):

You should use DenseHistogram class if you want to use EmguCV.
I'll show you basic usage:

```
  // Create a grayscale image
  Image<Gray, Byte> img = new Image<Gray, byte>(400, 400);
  // Fill image with random values
  img.SetRandUniform(new MCvScalar(), new MCvScalar(255));
  // Create and initialize histogram
  DenseHistogram hist = new DenseHistogram(256, new RangeF(0.0f, 255.0f));
  // Histogram Computing
  hist.Calculate<Byte>(new Image<Gray, byte>[] { img }, true, null);
```

There are a lot of other common methods inside DenseHistogram class such as Back Projection

Comment: thanx.. but i already calculate histogram using CvInvoke.cvCalHist(),
but i find above method is much easier to use.
Can you briefly elaborate difference between McvHistogram and DenseHistogram?

Comment: DenseHistogram is the managed class that wraps McvHistogram. You can inspect DenseHistogram class and check that it has a property MCvHistogram. My suggestion is to not use cvinvoke when opencv functionality has already been wrapped in proper managed class...

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code snippet:

```
histogramBox.GenerateHistograms(image,bin);               
histogramBox2.Refresh();
```

It will create a histogram of your picture automatically.

Comment: how do you know what value to pass for bin?

Comment: Also, why do you have two histogram boxes?