# ToolTip use to show the index of an item from a collection. C# WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, tooltip

I'm plotting a histogram of a grayscale image using an array of 256 values. Im doing so by creating my own chart with 256 vertical rectangles (columns). My aim is that when I mouse over one rectangle I get its index value, its index from the array it lies in, like if I mouse over the 200th rectangle I get 200 in a small text box near cursor, like how ToolTip should perform. The problem is that I don't find the proper binding for ToolTip to get this working. I think the solution lies in the proper use of **AlternationCount**  / **AlternationIndex**

Here is may XAML code, maybe someone can give me a fix for it:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding HistogramValues}" AlternationCount="{Binding Path=HistogramValues.Count}">              
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Height="{Binding }" ToolTip="{Binding AlternationIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" Width="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Fill="Black"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> 
</ItemsControl>
```

where in view model I have:

```
public float[] HistogramValues { get; set; }
```

I've found this useful post 
[Numbered listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745568/numbered-listbox/748383)
but I still cant make it run for my case, I'm confused about that **ItemTemplate** and **TemplatedParent** which I dont know if I need or if I need the template how should I code this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not ok with converters you can use this,

```
 <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" AlternationCount="{Binding Path=Collection.Count}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex),   RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContentPresenter}}">
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Since AlternationIndex is attached property, it should be covered with "()".

Comment: I think my issue was in how I specify the RelativeSource for Tooltip. I dont fully understand why, but your solution its working :), thx.

Comment: And when you said "Since AlternationIndex is attached property, it should be covered with "()" you meant that Path value should be inside bracers ? like (ItemsControl.AlternationIndex) ? ... didn't knew that, or I wasn't aware of the differences :(

Comment: ItemsControl generates ItemsContainer for each item in itemssource :) To each ItemContainer it sets AlternationIndex property.

The ItemsContainer is of type ContentPresenter. Into each ContentPresenter is then loaded instance of your DataTemplate. In your binding you need to get AlternationIndex property of current ItemContainer. Since ItemContainer is ContentPresenter in this case, you need to find ancestor of type ContentPresenter. E.g for listbox it would be listboxitem.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont specify source in a binding, it always binds to datacontext.

Do this

```
ToolTip="{Binding (ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter}}"
```

Comment: I've done what you said. I've edited the code with the line you gave me. When I mouse over on a rectangle, Tooltip shows 0 no matter what rectangle I select. So it shows only 0 :(

Comment: Set AlternationCount to very big number, ideally int.MaxValue. I guess there is an binding error message in your output window, when debugging, saying property Count does not exist on type array. Array has Lenght property instead of Count, unlike List

Comment: something like this ? AlternationCount="2147483647". It still dosent work, I just tried and I've tried with other values as well :(

Comment: why cant you have an another property holding the index in HistogramValue and bind it to the Tooltip? is there restriction in your requirement?

Comment: It must work, I have done it dozens of times. Do you have some warning in output window when debugging?

Comment: I was always aware of the solution you said here in the comment kumar, having another property to hold the index. But that solution is not as neat given the fact that I only want to show the index (which is basically the pixel value) and in order to set the new index property I have to wrap the array to a new array of objects holding the index and the value which is a bit odd. I've done that in the end, but now I've changed it back to the solution you gave me below and it works (the one with tooltip).

Comment: Thanks for your input as well Liero :D

Comment: I have edited my answer and it works now. I made mistake in AncestorType. I think this is much better solution than MultiConverter

Comment: Well, yes :D, is essentially the same thing as kumar said isn't it ?, for the ToolTip

Answer (score 0):

If showing the index is your only requirement you can achieve this like below,,
MyConverter is a multiconverter ,and include that in resources

```
     <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="Control.ToolTip">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="IsMouseOver" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                    <Binding />
                                    <Binding Path="ItemsSource" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>

  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<string> collection;

        public ObservableCollection<string> Collection
        {
            get { return collection; }
            set { collection = value; }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            collection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            collection.Add("First");
            collection.Add("Second");
            collection.Add("Third");
            collection.Add("Fourth");

        }
    }

     public class MyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                if ((bool)values[0])
                {
                    return (values[2] as ObservableCollection<string>).IndexOf(values[1].ToString());
                }
                else
                    return "";
            }

            public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```