# emgu Calculate histogram with matrices

Tags: c#, .net, emgucv

I found a similar question: [creating histogram using emgu cv c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905893/creating-histogram-using-emgu-cv-c-sharp)
and it works well when i passed grayscaled images, but when i use the Matrix, program throws exceptions. my code:

```
Matrix<double> mat = new Matrix<double>(10, 10);
mat.SetRandUniform(new MCvScalar(0.0), new MCvScalar(20.0));
DenseHistogram histo = new DenseHistogram(5, new RangeF(0.0f, 20.0f));
histo.Calculate(new Matrix<double>[] { mat }, false, null);//<--throws exception here
CvInvoke.cvShowImage("Mat Histogram", histo.GetHistogramImage().Ptr);
CvInvoke.cvWaitKey(0);
```

and the declaration in emgu doc is:

```
public void Calculate<TDepth>(
    Matrix<TDepth>[] matrices,
    bool accumulate,
    Matrix<byte> mask
)
where TDepth : new()
```

i cant figure out what's wrong :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing off consist on a limitation in  ***DenseHistogram*** class that when invoking ***cvCalcArrHist***  throws an "Unsupported format or combination of formats".

This class compute only on float and not on double.

```
Matrix<float> mat = new Matrix<float>(10, 10);
mat.SetRandUniform(new MCvScalar(0.0), new MCvScalar(20.0));
DenseHistogram histo = new DenseHistogram(5, new RangeF (0.0f, 20.0f));
histo.Calculate(new Matrix<float>[] { mat }, false, null); //runs fine :)
```

A better design should also let the user specify also ranges using generics, `Range<double>` instead of static `RangeF` class.