# Any idea how to get background color of the poster or broadsheet?

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, opencv, emgucv

In my project Im using EMGU librery.

I need to determine the background color of the urban poster or broadsheet.

As I see the background color of the poster or broadsheet is the predominant color.

My question if Emgu has any function that returns(in certain existing models BGR,HSL...) predominant color or some usefull results about colors in the image,
If not , any idea how can I achieve my goal in effective way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a [histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905893/creating-histogram-using-emgu-cv-c-sharp) of the image.  The color that occurs the most will be the background color.

Answer (score 2):

I think you must first define what predominant color is.

Do you mean illumination color, average color, mode, or even median?

Latter three are easy to calculate but first one is not.

If you think background color is the color you want. You first need to find a way to isolate that background with some masking technique. And then you can calculate mean, mode, or median of pixels in that background for predominant color.